# Como chamar duas funções no onClick (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, funções, react, onclick

Aqui estão minhas duas funções,

```
chamaLogin = () => {
            this.setState({
                redirect: true
            });
        };

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
handleSubmit = event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const arrInsert = {
              nome: this.state.nome,
              apelido: this.state.apelido
            };

            axios.post("http://localhost:3000", arrInsert)
              .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
              })    

          }
```

Como posso chamar essas duas funções no onClick ?

Comment: Insira como está o seu onClick e o que de fato ele está chamando agora.

Comment: apenas : onClick={this.handleSubmit}

Comment: Queria chamar as duas funções ao mesmo tempo ou uma após a outra?

Comment: pode ser uma após a outra, pra ficar melhor o carregamento...
Então seria: primeiro a handleSubmit depois a chamaLogin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens de chamar uma dentro da outra. Podes encontrar um nome mais genérico e chamar as duas dentro dessa outra função de nome mais genérico mas só podes ter um `onClick` por elemento.

Por vezes faz sentido ter um auscultador de evento no elemento/componente pai e outro no filho, ou ter um em `capture` e outro quando a propagação vem do elemento... mas na maioria dos casos chamar duas funções é o que faz mais sentido:

No JSX:

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

e no componente:

```
handleClick(e){
    this.chamaLogin();
    this.handleSubmit(e);
}
```

Se as quiseres encadear:

No caso da Promise seria :

```
.then(() => this.chamaLogin());
```

No caso do `setState` seria teoricamente:

```
chamaLogin(e){
    this.setState({
        redirect: true
    }, () => this.handleSubmit(e));
```

**mas** ter uma referência assíncrona ao objeto do evento (`e`) não vai fazer o que esperas pois o `.preventDefault()` já não vai funcionar, o evento já foi "consumido".

Comment: Obrigada!!! funcionou

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz de uma forma bem parecida do que o Sérgio sugeriu, mas sem usar o `this`. Aqui, eu chamo uma view (`goToSendPage`) com o click do botão e também envio dados para um endpoint (`apiCallData`). Minha aplicação é SPA (Single Page App).

Meu componente:

```
const SendButton = (props) => {
  const { goToSendPage, id, clientNumber, countNumber } = props;
  
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    goToSendPage();
    const key = "sendData";
    const value = `cliente: ${clientNumber},${countNumber}`;
    apiCallData(id, key, value);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        classes={{ root: classes.root }}
        target="_blank"
        style={{ justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center" }}
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default SendButton;
```

Na [documentação do React](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) tem isso bem explicadinho, caso voce queira ler depois :)